# Python: Removing image margins and applying same transformation to another image

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation

Dear stackoverflow community,

I encountered an issue when preparing data for an image segmentation project. An example of my image is below.
It has white margins, and these white margins have black margins around them. If you look closely, you will notice the actual image is not even vertical. Is there a way to remove all the surrounding margins and align the central part (including the black background) vertically? Any transformation on the image needs to be applied to its segmentation mask (below) as well. The segmentation mask has the same dimension as the original image. Thank you so much in advance.

[image]

[image: corresponding segmentation mask]

Comment: morphology operations could help. look for processing that would be done on scans of photos. those usually have black or white borders. -- and you should provide the full resolution source image, not a thumbnail of a plot of the picture. then people can try things before they answer...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you. My image is over 2MB, how could I upload it in Stackoverflow?

Comment: just make it a jpeg and squeeze it gently until it fits within 2 MB. or reduce the dimensions by a factor of 2.